# Не получается использовать словарь, который получен путём парсинга

Tags: python, selenium, dict, eval

С помощью Selenium Python получаю содержимое тега script, которое является словарем. Но при попытке получить его ключи получал ошибку что это строка. Пытаюсь преобразовать в словарь с помощью eval, но тоже получаю ошибку. Пробовал использовать eval, который из библиотеки, та же ошибка. Вот код:

```
script_raw = driver.find_element_by_id('__NEXT_DATA__').get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(script_raw)

script = eval(str(script_raw))
print(script)
```

Ошибка:

```
script = eval(str(script_raw))
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

Первый принт выводит следующий текст:

```
{"props":{"pageProps":{"initialApolloState":{"ROOT_QUERY":{"__typename":"Query","sticker({\"input\":{\"id\":\"sticker-advent-katowice-2019\"}})":{"_id":"sticker-advent-katowice-2019","name":"Наклейка | advent | Katowice 2019","title":" advent | Katowice 2019"...
```

Не понимаю в чём ошибка. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас там где-то в недрах текста есть элемент вроде такого:

```
"some_elementh": null
```

Питон не понимает, что такое `null` и во что ему его преобразовывать когда он делает `eval`, это не питоновский объект. Есть два варианта решения:

- Завести заранее переменную `null = None`, тогда `eval` возможно отработает, если не споткнётся на чём-то ещё
- Работать с `json` как с `json`, а не через небезопасный `eval` - используйте библиотеку `json` и функцию `json.loads(script_raw)` для разбора `json` структуры в питоновские объекты